# Isomorphism of vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F}$ to $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Show that $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F},V)$.

This is easily proven when $V$ is finite-dimensional. However, I'm not quite sure how to prove/disprove it if $V$ is infinite-dimensional.

As the first answer belows suggests, we can show that these two spaces are isomorphic. But now I'm not sure how to show that this map is surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\Phi : V\to \mathcal L(\mathbb F,V)$ by $\Phi(v) = f_v$, $v\in V$. Here, $f_v : \mathbb F\to V$ is defined by $f_v(t) = tv$, $t\in\mathbb F$, and show that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism. For this, note that $f\in\mathcal L(\mathbb F,V)$ implies $f(t) = f(t\cdot 1) = tf(1)$.

Comment: Wait but how to you show this map is surjective?

Comment: Please read my answer completely.

Comment: It's too succinct to be understood easily by a newcomer to theoretical linear algebra like me. Anyway, I've figured out how to prove it is injective... Thank you for your response!

Comment: I have to write everything out by myself to fully understand it, and now I do. :P

Comment: So, you can prove surjectivity now?

Comment: Oh yeah, just feed f(1) into $\Phi$ for any f.

Comment: Exactly. Thumbs up!